# Windows Store - dynamic styling

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, styling

I am creating a windows store application that currently loads a simple class (which loads 5 items).

I use a simple grid to load the items in and then set some styling;

code snippet;

```
<Grid  Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="261,111,10,302">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="lstMatters" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tapped="spMatter_Tapped" >
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource MatterImage}"></Image>
                        <GridView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle1}" SelectionMode="None">
                            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <GridViewItem Margin="3" Style="{StaticResource gridViewHeader}" Content="FileRef: " FontSize="20"></GridViewItem>
                            <GridViewItem Margin="3" Content="{Binding Path=FileRef}" FontSize="20"></GridViewItem>
                            <GridViewItem Margin="3" Style="{StaticResource gridViewHeader}" Content="Description: " FontSize="20"></GridViewItem>
                            <GridViewItem Margin="3" Content="{Binding Path=Description}" FontSize="20"></GridViewItem>
                            <GridViewItem Margin="3" Style="{StaticResource gridViewHeader}" Content="DocumentSet: " FontSize="20"></GridViewItem>
                            <GridViewItem Margin="3" Content="{Binding Path=DocumentSet}" FontSize="20"></GridViewItem>
                            <GridViewItem Margin="3" Style="{StaticResource gridViewHeader}" Content="MatterType: " FontSize="20"></GridViewItem>
                            <GridViewItem Margin="3" Content="{Binding Path=MatterType}" FontSize="20"></GridViewItem>
                        </GridView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

I am trying to create a "dynamic" style in the sence that, when the DocumentSet column loads and displays in the grid, the code will do a type of "switch" statement and according to the DocumentSet, use a spesific style.
(i.e. change the gridViewItem's style depending on the DocumentSet's value.

```
Switch DocumentSet
Case "a"
 style = style.a
Case "b"
 style = style.b)
```

Hope that made sense?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this video by Jerry Nixon. It is basically to show how to implement interstitial ads, but you can use same concept by using the ListView.ItemTemplateSelector.

http://youtu.be/kTBdCgVVjug

Arun